# Copy value of watch variable in visual studio without escape characters

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Ok, this one has been driving me bonkers for ages and VS 2010 hasn't improved this. Say I have a variable like so

```
string szSql = 
@"SELECT 
     Foo, Bar
FROM
     Table
WHERE
     Foo = Bar";
```

If I'm inspecting this in the debugger and choose "Copy Value" the value put into the clipboard has \r\n's in place of the carriage returns which is a bit of a pain. Is there a way to change this behaviour? (I know I can print it in the command window...)

Cheers,

Alex

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Append `,nq` (short for no quotes) to the variable name in the watch window and it will display the string without escape characters, which you could then copy. For reference the MSDN document is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e514eeby(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: You can do this trick from the immediate window as well. ?szSql,nq

Comment: Anything to avoid the double quotes when right clicking on a value in the code and selecting Copy Value?

Comment: Hm... when I try this, I get "'nq' is not defined."

Comment: sweet, works in vscode too. Type `mySQLString,nq` into "DEBUG CONSOLE" while on a breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful when debugging JSON in variables

Comment: This is a life changer

Comment: Wow! I have probably wanted this for a long time, but I didn't think to search on this until today! thanks for the tip. It was a bit tricky to get it to work in VS2019 - the Watch Window I was in was saying that my variable didn't exist. But I highlighted the variable in the code and right menu gave me the option to add it to the watch window, then I added ",nq" to the end of it and it worked!

Answer (score 19):

Use the "text visualizer" popup on the value and copy it to the clipboard from there.  It will be unescaped.

Comment: Hmm, not ideal, still an extra couple of clicks to get it in the clipboard.

Thanks though!!!!

Answer (score 2):

For lengthy text, such as a large xml document, I always use the immediate window.  Just type this in and hit enter:

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(szSql)`

and it will spit out the text with line breaks and without escape characters.  I then copy from the immediate window.

Comment: Or you could just type ? szSql - as I said I knew this but it's a lot of extra keypresses.

Comment: Holy smokes, I love ? szSql!