# How can I remove the escape characters from this string?

Tags: c#

I have a string called **argument** that I need to send to a process.  My argument was built and when I check the value from the immediate window I get this:

```
argument
" -i \"M:\\visual studio 2013\\cherry\\Database\\script.sql\" -v varDb=foobar"
```

what I want is to have this: (replace \ with \ and replace \" with ")

```
argument
" -i "M:\visual studio 2013\cherry\Database\script.sql" -v varDb=foobar"
```

I'm somewhat embarrassed I have to ask this, but I've tried all sorts of .Replace and regex expressions already.

Comment: You already have what you want. The immediate window doesn't interpret escape characters.

Comment: Duplicate of (with better answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327540/copy-value-of-watch-variable-in-visual-studio-without-escape-characters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The immediate window is showing it to you escaped because that's how it displays a string. You don't have any escape characters in the actual string.

You can't manage to remove them cause they're not actually there. It's a display feature of the immediate window.

I suspect the real issue must be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Ugh.. There was no issue, but I was testing the output on th cmd line

Answer (score 8):

As has been mentioned by others, the immediate window shows the unescaped string (by default). This can be changed using format specifiers ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e514eeby%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).
Appending `,nq` should remove escape chars

See: [Copy value of watch variable in visual studio without escape characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327540/copy-value-of-watch-variable-in-visual-studio-without-escape-characters) for an example