# Unescape a string in C# Interactive

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-interactive

In VS 14 if I type (in the C# Interactive window) for examle `Environment.CurrentDirectory` it says `"C:\\Users\\some.username"`. How can I get `"C:\Users\some.username"` instead, without manually deleting characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the escape characters from this string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289922/how-can-i-remove-the-escape-characters-from-this-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Console.WriteLine(value)`:

```
> Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
C:\Users\
>
```

Comment: It would, technicaly, be `Console.WriteLine($"\"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\"")`. :)

Answer (score 3):

The debugger will show it as double slash but if you check the variable, it will be with the single slash. The debugger displays it as you would expect when escaping in C# code but the underlying value is what you would expect (i.e "C:\Users\some.username").

Comment: Debugger? The question asks about C# Interactive.

Comment: That's true, my bad. Principle still stands, possibly because it's using the same display method as the debugger.