# C# download HTML page to string asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to download a aspx page's html from an another page, using the following code:

```
  WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
             String CompleteReport = webClient.DownloadString(new System.Uri(reportURL));
```

however the HTML that is returned contains the markup similar to the following:

```
"\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"
```

what should i do to download a string without these escape sequences.

Thank You!

Comment: What markup - the embeded CRLF ("\r\n") ? What would you expect to see in place of a carriage return/line feed pair ?

Comment: none, i just want the html without the escape sequences, 
This HTML would an another html page,

Comment: @PhillipH yeah, silly me, forgot about encodings.... thanks for you help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string doesn't actually contain those sequences.  It contains the characters that they represent (actual newline and linefeed characters).

You are probably viewing the string in a debugger and the debugger is adding those sequences for you.  If you dump it to a file and read it in notepad they won't be there.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327540/copy-value-of-watch-variable-in-visual-studio-without-escape-characters?noredirect=1&lq=1).  If you add `,nq` to the variable name in the watch window, the escape sequences will go away.

Comment: yeah, just figured that out, thanks!! Silly me, :)
Thank you guys for the help!.

:)