# "Copy Value" of string in debugger gets an escaped string but I want the actual value (non-escaped)

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019 debug mode it's possible to hover over variables to show their value and then right-click to "Copy", "Copy Expression" or "Copy Value".  When I'm doing a "Copy Value" of a string I want it to copy the strings's value not it's escaped value.  Is there any way to change this behavior or is there a different way to do this, maybe an extension or something I can add that will give me another choice to get the non-escaped value?

The way I currently workaround this is I have to move my curser to the left and click on the magnifying glass icon to open the preview dialog then do a Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C from there and although this works it's really annoying.  I'm hoping there's a better way!

Comment: Does [Copy value of watch variable in visual studio without escape characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327540/copy-value-of-watch-variable-in-visual-studio-without-escape-characters) give you a useful route?

Comment: Not really, I'm really looking for a context menu solution.  That seems like more effort than my current workaround.